# Let B be a square matrix such that rank(B)=rank(B^2). Show that (the nullspace of B) ∩ (the column space of B) = {0}

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B be a square matrix such that rank(B)=rank(B^2). Show that (the nullspace of B) ∩ (the column space of B) = {0}
I know that their nullspace is equal since their rank is equal. Any clues on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What has $A$ to do with $B$?

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrongly. Just edited it.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you explain why rank $ (B^2) \leq$ rank (B) always?

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $\mathrm{Im}(B)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(B^2)$ the images (i.e. the column spaces) of $B$ and $B^2$ respectively. One has always $\mathrm{Ker}(B) \subset \mathrm{Ker}(B^2)$. But because $\mathrm{Im}(B)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(B^2)$ are supposed to have the same dimension, then by rank theorem, $\mathrm{Ker}(B)$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(B^2)$ also share the same dimension. You deduce that $\mathrm{Ker}(B^2)=\mathrm{Ker}(B)$.

Now, if $x \in \mathrm{Ker}(B) \cap \mathrm{Im}(B)$, then $x=B(y)$ for some element $y$, and $B(x)=0$, so $B^2(y)=0$, so $y \in \mathrm{Ker}(B^2)=\mathrm{Ker}(B)$, so $B(y)=0$, so $x=0$.